# Python pop() does not remove the item

Tags: python-2.7

I am working on a function that convert a multi-level dictionary to a list of one-level dictionaries.

The logic seems right. But when I run it, the while loop runs infinity. I found the first time it went into the while loop, `next_level.pop()` was working. Starting from the second time of the while loop, the `pop()` function never remove the last item of `next_level`. I also tried to retrieve the last item by `next_level[-1]`, and delete the last item by `del next_level[-1]`. But the result is the same. I think it could be related to the reference thing. Any idea?

```
def flat_dict(self, params):
    """convert a multi-level dictionary to a list of one-level dictionaries"""
    plist = next_level = []
    next_level.append(params)
    while next_level:
        current_level = temp_level = next_level.pop()
        for k, v in current_level.iteritems():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                next_level.append(temp_level.pop(k))
                pk = [x for x in next_level[-1].keys() if x.endswith('_id')]
                temp_level[pk[0]] = next_level[-1][pk[0]]
        plist.append(temp_level)
    return plist
```

Comment: The `pop()` function seems to work reliably for me. Can you explain what you mean by "I think it could be related to the reference thing"?

Comment: Could you please explain more about what you are trying to do?  I find your code difficult to follow so I would like more explanation.

Comment: @GregHewgill Because python is pass-by-reference when the object is mutable. So I just guess it could be related.

Comment: @steveha The `params` is a multi-level dict. In my code, I am trying to convert the multi-level dict to a `list` of single-level `dict`. It is like BFS to convert a tree to a list. But in my case, I need to get the 'id' from the lower level dict and plug into the upper level for reference.

Comment: What is this 'id' you are getting?  Your code calls the `dict.keys()` method and grabs the 0th key, but a `dict` is not ordered, so `.keys()` can return the keys in any order, so I don't understand why you do this.

Comment: @steveha this 'id' is like `'source_id': '123BA'` and `'article_id': '81762936'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an example of the dictionary, its a little hard to visualize...but generally for a case like this, I'd recommend recursion anyway:

```
def flatten( data ):
    output = []
    if ( isinstance(data, dict) ):
        output.append(data)
        for value in data.values():
            output += flatten(value)
    return output
```

In direct answer to your question tho, I'm not 100% sure what is going wrong - I can say that pop() itself will work just fine.  I'm guessing it has to do with the way you're initializing the plist, are you getting an infinite loop?

```
plist = next_level = []
```

This line is actually setting plist and next_level to the *same exact* list - not initializing a blank list for each variable.

```
>>> plist = next_level = []
>>> plist.append(1)
>>> next_level
[1]
```

When you modify plist, later in your loop, you're actually modifying the next_level also which is not what is intended is my guess...try defining your plist/next_level this way:

```
plist = []
next_level = []
```

And see what happens.

Comment: Yes, the chain assignment causes this problem. I should not use chain assignment for init mutable variables. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely understand what you are trying to do, so I don't think this answer will be exactly what you need.  But perhaps you can use it as the start of a solution.

This answer does not mutate the `dict` to be flattened; it just walks over it and builds a list of new `dict` instances.  It calls itself recursively to flatten an arbitrarily nested `dict`.

```
def flat_dict(self, d_to_flatten, lst_flat=None):
    """convert a multi-level dictionary to a list of one-level dictionaries"""
    if lst_flat is None:
        lst_flat = []

    d = {}
    lst = []
    for k, v in d_to_flatten.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            lst.append(v)
        else:
            d[k] = v
    lst_flat.append(d)
    for d in lst:
        flat_dict(self, d, lst_flat)

    return lst_flat
```